# Does msiexec have a builtin timeout?

Tags: timeout, windows-installer

If a program has problems during an install/uninstall/repair in windows, leaving it stuck during a particular operation, does msiexec.exe eventually die based on a built-in timeout? Does it output a particular line recognizable in the log it for later review?